# Converting IEEE 754 packed bit stream into float single precision

Tags: c, floating-point, converters, ieee-754

I have a problem with converting unsigned long to Float single precision
Here is my problem

I need to communicate in floating point in my program, but all my internal variables are unsigned long, So the design we decided was such that everything will remain same,(in unsigned long) and once a float needs to be given to application, i will convert to float and pass it on.

So all the variables will have a IEEE 754 bit stream according to

[Float converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/)

Steps i follow :

1. I get the value in char array
2. I take the bits and copy into a unsigned long
3. While giving the data on function call, i typecast to float single precision.

In debugger i see the same bit pattern (in buffers) for steps 1 &2

In step 3 too, i see the same binary pattern, but the value is not interpreted as a float

Input  : 21.125

1. Binary : 01000001101010010000000000000000
2. Hex    : 0x41a90000
3. Decimal: 1101594624

   ```
   Code:
   void ApplicationApi(void * DataPtr)
   {
   (*(float32*)((void*)DataPtr))= unsignedLong_val;
   }
   ```

Result in application DataPtr 
* DataPtr = 1.101594624 * e9

Am i missing something here or the type case worked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard C way to reinterpret the bytes of an `unsigned long` as a `float` is:

```
y = (union { unsigned long u; float f; }) { x } .f;
```

This code defines a compound literal that is a union, and it initializes the union with the value of `x`, which should be an `unsigned long`. Then it accesses the `f` member of the union, which is a `float`. This `float` value is assigned to `y`, which should be a `float`.

Thus, assuming the declaration of `ApplicationApi` must remain the same and that the `void *DataPtr` it is passed is the result of converting a pointer to a `float` to a pointer to `void`, its definition could be:

```
void ApplicationApi(void *DataPtr)
{
    * (float32 *) DataPtr =(union { unsigned long u; float32 f; }) { unsignedLong_val } .f;
}
```

Notes about this code:

- This requires that `unsigned long` and `float32` have the same size.
- It is undesirable for `unsignedLong_val` to have file scope. It would be preferable to pass it as a parameter.
- There is no reason inherent in this code that DataPtr should be passed as a `void *`. It could be passed as a `float32 *`.

Notes about code leading up to this code:

- The way that the bytes have been assembled in the `unsigned long` may have endian issues.
- In C implementations that are currently rare, an `unsigned long` could have trap values that prevent it from being used to hold arbitrary bytes.

About the C standard and reinterpreting bytes:

- Reinterpreting bytes through a union is the result of C 2011 (N1570) 6.5.2.3 3, which says that an expression using the `.` operator and a member name has the value of the named member. Note 95 of the standard indicates that this may be used to reinterpret bytes.
- Another supported way to reinterpret bytes is by converting a pointer to a pointer to a character type and using the new pointer to copy bytes, per 6.3.2.3 7. (`memcpy` is sometimes used for this.)
- 6.3.2.3 7 defines this behavior only for pointers to character types. For other types, the C standard generally does not define the behavior of converting a pointer to a pointer of another type and dereferencing the result. Therefore, the behavior of code that does this is undefined. Even if it appears to work in a test, it may later fail due to compiler optimizations or other effects.

Comment: Is there a way to do this operation without using Union ?

Comment: @DarkKnight: You can use `memcpy` to copy the bytes of an `unsigned long` into a `float32`.

Comment: 1. So a type cast is not needed and memcpy would suffice ? 2. Will this work for double precision floats too ?

Comment: @DarkKnight: As the answer states, you may either use a union or use `memcpy`. Both of these methods may be used to copy the bytes of one object of any type into another object of any type, and the bytes will be reinterpreted as a value of the new type.

Comment: This matches my requirement precisely

Answer (score -1):

Try with this cast :

```
void ApplicationApi(void * DataPtr)
{
  *(float32*)DataPtr = *(float32*)unsignedLong_val;
}
```

You have to declare that the right value is a float value.
With your cast, the right value is an integer and the left value a float. The compiler convert implicitly the integer to a float value.

Comment: Thanks Micheal, Just modified a little    void ApplicationApi(void * DataPtr)
{
  *(float32*)DataPtr = *(float32*)(&unsignedLong_val);
} Does any compiler dependecy change the output ? also in the reverse direction

Comment: This is not valid C. It violates the aliasing rules, meaning roughly that the compiler may reorder/rearrange/optimize code in a way that results in different behavior from what you expect. (Formally, it's just undefined behavior.)

Comment: @R.. where is there two different pointers of two different type pointing at the same memory location ? There is no violation of aliasing rule.

Comment: @Michael R.. is referring to C99 6.5:7, which mentions the “effective type” of the object, defined in 6.5:6. If `unsignedLong_val` is of type `unsigned long`, and/or if `DataPtr` points to an object that will be accessed with a type other than `float32`, you function participates to undefined behavior in the complete program. The only cases in which it does not invoke undefined behavior are the cases in which it does not solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @PascalCuoq : In my casr the DataPtr will point to float32 and I am type casting as below....    (*Astrick(float32**)((void*)DataPtr)) = (*Astrick(float32**)((void*)&signalDataVal));, I guess this should not have a problem , * do not appear thats why Astrick

Comment: @DarkKnight: Converting pointers like that is not supported by the C standard. The behavior is undefined. In your latest comment `signalDataVal` is presumably an `unsigned long`. The behavior of converting it to `void *` and then to `float32 *` and then dereferencing it is not defined by the C standard.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks for your comment... Infact it is a problem i realise it. I would want to understand what could go wrong with the below code                                                                uint32 var;
(*float32*(DataPtr)) = (*(const float32*)((const void*)&var))...                                                     Waiting for your inputs

Comment: uint32 var; (Astrick(float32*)(DataPtr)) = (Astrick(const float32*)((const void*)&var)).